# SEO in AJAX-links

Tags: jquery, seo

I have a couple of questions about loading pages with AJAX and Jquery - heres what im using to load external .html-pages without reloading index-page:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#content").load(page + ".html");
        return false;
});

<a href="page_one.html#page_one"> 1 </a>
<a href="page_two.html?page_two"> 1 </a>

<div id="content"> ..content from ext pages load here.. </div>
```

Q1: What does "return false" actually do here?
Q2: Will the link "page_one.html#page_one" get indexed by Google?
Q3: Should i be using hash-tag or ? in the links - both seems to be working so whats the differnece?

Hope someone has the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "return false" actually do here?

As John Conde explained this prevents the browser from following the hyperlink (e.g. to the page page_one.html#page_one rather than just loading it with AJAX).

> Will the link "page_one.html#page_one" get indexed by Google?

Yes, the page `page_one.html` will. The `#page_one` part will be ignored. From any web crawler's perspective `<a href="page_one.html#page_one"> 1 </a>` is a completely standard anchor tag. However I'm guessing, that page_one.html is not a complete web page with navigation and stuff, but rather simply the page content? So you may not want to have that page indexed by Google.

> Should i be using hash-tag or ? in the links - both seems to be working so whats the difference?

You shouldn't really need any of them. Since you are not using the hash fragment `#page_one` (in your javascript) you can remove it (it was useful for keeping track of AJAX state before HTML5 History manipulation was widely supported across browsers. Hash fragments can also be used for jumping to somewhere on the page. I.e. clicking an URL ending in `#header1` would cause the browser to jump to an HTML element with `id="header1"` (but this is not relevant for your case). The `?page_one` is usually used for supplying extra parameters for some server-side script (such as a PHP script) and thus it makes little sense for a flat HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which clarifies everything. Except im a little confused regarding the indexing of "empty" pages - you are right about the pages being loaded by Jquery contains only elements with content and no head or body, metatags, and so on - why is it bad for that page to get indexed? And whats the alternative - the content of the external pages has to be indexed - if not, the entire website would only consist of a single page with some nav on it..?!

Comment: @KennethHayes If a page without navigation is indexed, then that's the page a user will see if he finds it through Google.
I find the best solution is to use PHP (or some other server-side scripting) to create both the pure-content version (without navigation, head, meta,..) and the full-page dynamically.
As an example _yoursite.com/page_one.php_ could return the full page and _yoursite.com/page_one.php?viewMode=ajax_ could return only the pure-content version.
Then you can call `$("#content").load(page + "?viewMode=ajax");` in your javascript to retrieve the page without menus.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "return false" actually do here?

Stops the browser from following through with the default action of the element which in this case is to follow the hyperlink

> Will the link "page_one.html#page_one" get indexed by Google?

No. This does not meet [Google's crawlable Ajax standard](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)

> Should i be using hash-tag or ? in the links - both seems to be working so whats the differnece?

It doesn't matter if it works. But if you want it to be search engine friendly you will need to find an alternative way to do this.

Comment: [This post about Google and AJAX](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) is more current and accurate.

Comment: I know about 'pushstate' which is probably the thing i have to implement in order to get SEO in links - however i dont understand why the bot wont accept the first part of link before the hash - the link is there, but maybe thats just the way it is..

Id still like to know the difference between # and ? in links

Comment: When you request a URL in your browser the hash fragment #blabla is not sent to the server. It's a client side thing only. The query part ?blabla on the other hand _is_ sent to the server. The web server can serve different content depending on the ?blabla part, but not the #blabla. Sorry for not making myself clear on that initially.